# Creating a server-side time activated process

Tags: process

What is the method for creating a process on the server that checks the date on a daily basis and will start another process when the criteria is met?

Answer (score 2):

If we're talking about a Linux server, you might want to [look into crontab](http://www.tech-geeks.org/contrib/mdrone/cron&crontab-howto.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Scheduled tasks on windows.
Start->Programs->Accessories->SystemTools->Scheduled tasks.